# C vs C++ - advantages with c-language

Tags: c++, c

C++, as the name suggests, is a superset of C. As a matter of fact, C++ can run most of C code while C cannot run C++ code.

There are several advantages with c++ compared with c - for instance

- data can not be hidden in c language
- c is more low level (which mean harder to understand and code - and that means more bugs)
- c does not allow function overloading
- c does not support exception handling
- you can use functions inside structures in C++ but not in C

This list could certainly be much longer - but here comes my question: Is there ANY advantage with c-langauge compared with c++? Is there anything whatsoever that is better with c than with c++? Does c have anything that c++ lacks?

I do not know about this at all - but could c possibly be slighty faster than c++ due to fewer instruction-sets? A low-level language would possibly require fewer instructions by the processor.

Comment: It's not a superset of C. And its name implies that it is 1 more than C (unless C is the maximum representable value for its type).

Comment: support in embedded systems and/with custom compilers comes to mind

Comment: It's name implies that after evaluating, C is one more than C++ :)

Comment: This question is so broad, I wanted to give you an answer, but don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I really like C vs C++ comparisons, but I think that C and C++ are pretty different languages.

Comment: "c is more low level" that can be seen as an advantage, depending on the context.

Comment: `C++, as the name suggests, is a superset of C.` No, it's not. `data can not be hidden in c language` Yes, it can.

Comment: @sftrabbit, If C is unsigned and reaches its maximum power, C++ will be 0 :(

Comment: I wouldn't really say C is much more low level, either. C++ gets down to the nitty-gritty just as well if you need it to.

Comment: C++ is not a strict superset of C. There are valid C programs that are invalid C++, and there are valid C programs that are valid C++ programs different semantics. It's possible, and not too difficult, to write code that's valid C and C++ with the same semantics -- but there's rarely a good reason to do so.

Comment: @sftrabbit  The initial C++ compiler was a translator that took the C++ source code, translated it into C source code and then compiled.  So at that time, _Anything_ C++ could do, C could also, but not necessarily the other way around, making C++ a functional _subset_ of C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497786/why-would-anybody-use-c-over-c

Comment: I might be going too far with this one, but you can overload functions based on the number of parameters in C by using variadic macros. See `BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD`, but substitute a normal function for the overloaded macro.

Comment: "Is there any advantage" - you just listed all the reasons!

Comment: "c is more low level (which mean harder to understand and code - and that means more bugs)" - Well I'mnot convinced that C is more "low level" than C++, but regardless, is the conclusion true?  I am experienced in both languages, and let me tell you; some C++ features allow for rather nasty, extremely subtle bugs to slip through which would be impossible in C.  Sounds like inexperience talking to me.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In simple, C and C++ are two different languages.

> C++, as the name suggests, is a superset of C

No. This is not true. [C++ is not a superset of C.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++).

> Is there ANY advantage with c-language compared with c++? Is there anything whatsoever that is better with c than with c++?
>
> - Static initialize is safe in C but not in C++, because in C++ static initialization can cause code to run, which depends on other variables having been statically initialized. It can also cause cleanup code to run at shutdown which you can't control sequence of (destructors).
> - C gives you better control over what happens when your code is executed. When reading seek out it is fairly straightforward to decipher one code is getting executed and when memory is just restart or primitive operations are performed.
> - C supports variable sized arrays on the stack. Which is much faster to allocate than on the heap. (C99 feature)
> - No name mangling. If you intend to read generated assembly code, this makes that much easier. It can be useful when trying to optimize code.
>     De facto standard application binary interface (ABI). Code produced by different compilers can easily be combined.
> - Much easier to interface with other languages. A lot of languages will let you call C functions directly. Binding to a C++ library is usually a much more elaborate job.
> - Compiling C programs is faster than compiling C++ programs, because parsing C is much easier than parsing C++.
> - Varargs cannot safely be used in C++. They're not entirely safe in in C either. However they're much more so in the C++, to the point that they are prohibited in the C++ coding standards (Sutter, Alexandrescu).
> - C requires less runtime support. Makes it more suitable for low-level environments such as embedded systems or OS components.
> - Standard way in C to do encapsulation is to forward declare a struct and only allow access to its data through functions. This method also creates compile time encapsulation. Compile time encapsulation allows us to change the data structures members without recompilation of client code (other code using our interface). The standard way of doing encapsulation C++ on the other hand (using classes) requires recompilation of client code when adding or removing private member variables.

Comment: Although I agree with the first half (about C and C++ beeing different), it's not answering the question..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; The two lines answers all the questions OP asked. The answer to this topic can be vast.

Comment: Yes, it's vast, which is why it's closed as "too broad": the precise opposite of what _you_ did, which is to give a placeholder non-answer that basically just says "don't bother with this question".

Comment: I do hope you did not mean `C` programs run faster than `C++` programs after they are built...

Comment: "Compiling C programs is faster than compiling C++ programs, because parsing C is much easier than parsing C++." Have you ever measured that? I seriously doubt that you can present a file for which this actually holds.

Comment: @haccks, many of the "advantages" you listed are your opinion or can't be proven.
"C supports variable sized arrays on the stack. Which is much faster to allocate than on the heap. (C99 feature)" Yeah but the stack is limited in size, so is this really an advantage?

Comment: @Miguel; That's why I never compare two languages with each other.

Comment: @haccks, except just now :P

Comment: Thats a pitty that this question was put on hold - and I dont understand why my question was heavily downvoted - at the most -3. And your answer should be more upvoted!!! Very good answer!!!! @haccks - thanks!!!!!

Comment: Yeah this answers to 3 of the 4 questions asked from where I see it. Why the criticism? Seems neutral and informative enough this one.